# Android NSD Host returns NULL

Tags: android, wifi, android-networking

I am currently using Network Service Discovery to detect HTTP services on my local network. I used the Google Android NSDChat project example, and it only returns to me the host names, however, the host IP address NULL.

This is my function that will return the host name

```
    public void onServiceFound(NsdServiceInfo service) {

        Log.d(TAG, "Service discovery success" + service.getHost());

        //pref.putString("name", service.getServiceName());
        if (!service.getServiceType().equals(SERVICE_TYPE)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Unknown Service Type: " + service.getServiceType());
        } else if (service.getServiceName().equals(mServiceName)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Same machine: " + mServiceName);
        } else if (service.getServiceName().contains(mServiceName)){
            mNsdManager.resolveService(service, mResolveListener);
        }


    }


public void initializeResolveListener() {

mResolveListener = new NsdManager.ResolveListener() {

    @Override
    public void onResolveFailed(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo, int errorCode) {
        // Called when the resolve fails.  Use the error code to debug.
        Log.e(TAG, "Resolve failed" + errorCode);
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceResolved(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Resolve Succeeded. " + serviceInfo);

        if (serviceInfo.getServiceName().equals(mServiceName)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Same IP.");
            return;
        }
        mService = serviceInfo;
        int port = mService.getPort();
        host = mService.getHost(); // getHost() will work now
        Log.d(TAG, "Service discovery success" + host );

    }
};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I face similar problem and I found this website. However after trying it, it did not work as well.

[Host is null in NsdServiceInfo of NsdManager.DiscoveryListener.onServiceFound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18094704/host-is-null-in-nsdserviceinfo-of-nsdmanager-discoverylistener-onservicefound?answertab=oldest#tab-top)